# Can someone help me determine what this SFX/onomatopoeia is?

Tags: translation, katakana, onomatopoeia, manga

Here's an image of it:

[image: Manga SFX]

It kind of looks like ダダ (da da) to me, but then I'm not sure what to make of the last mark. Could someone offer his insight, please?

Comment: What exactly is the action being performed here? Just grappling someone?

Comment: 柔道の場面かな。浦澤直樹のYAWARA!に見えます。。。

Comment: Have a look at this SFX database. It is important as a translator to provide the meaning of an effect so that the person who is going to think about an effect in English knows what would be most suitable. http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/index/ta/

Answer (score 1):

It's either ダダー or ダタッ. Given that if it were a ー on the end then it would probably be horizontally aligned with the other characters, I'm going to assume it's a ツ, and because ダタツ doesn't seem to make much sense as onomatopoeia, it should be a ッ (small-tsu). Given that it looks like a kind of shorter 'impact' sound and not something extended or ringing, I think we can rule out ダダー on both counts.

So my vote is for ダタッ!

Comment: I agree that it could be ダタッ but what does that mean?

Comment: I guess it's a sound like "data!"

Comment: Lol, can't imagine what that sounds like, I keep hearing 'tada~!' in my mind (the English one) and that doesn't fit the picture at all :(

Comment: Yeah try not to think about it too much. Manga writers can get pretty creative with their onomatopoeia. Just look at what's going on in the picture and try to imagine it said in a manner that might resemble what you would hear. That's the best advice I can offer.